# Service Stack returns IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

We have created a servicestack API on .NetCore3.1 (https://www.example.com). When there is a called made to the api with `https://www.example.com/http://test` or `https://www.example.com/php://test` we get IOException instead of 404 response.

It looks like its looking for that specific folder where we host our api.

Is there any flag in HostConfig that we can use to disabled this validation?

Errors:

- https://www.example.com/http://test : `IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : '{location}\http:'`
- https://www.example.com/php://test : `IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : '{location}\php:'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/44910dab91cb121e674d9af09e25b008596a3c7b) where ServiceStack will no longer attempt to access the file system for paths containing illegal characters.

This fix is available from v5.12.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget)

Comment: Thank you @mythz for the quick update. 
Any idea when this will be pushed or published to public nuget since we are not allowed to use private nuget feeds?

Comment: @NithinKumarNarayanaSwamy We just did a major release so the next one wont be for a while. Not until .NET 6 LTS is released at least. MyGet isn't private, it's a public NuGet feed which is used for customers to access our pre-release packages in between major releases. The alternative is building locally from GitHub and using a local build.